# Migration : if content migrated from tridion r5.XX to 2011?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-core-services

I have some legacy web sites on different platforms like tridion R5, cq, sitecore etc. Now i am migrating all of them into one tridion environment 2011. So i was wondering if i can migrate the website content which already in tridion R5, it'd be easy than migration from cq or sitecore. wanted to know the best way if i am using only static websites.

options :

1. Content Porter
2. Manual Content Creation
3. Any migration utility (can someone propose best utility for this)

for migration utility do we have some core services/ API for tridion R5.XX ?

Comment: You should probably ask this question on the Tridion StackExchange site: http://tridion.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Tridion and should be asked on tridion.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Manoj, I assume you are a developer just like the rest of us, but sometimes... sometimes we need to try to solve things the non-technical way.

Because in the end it is almost going to be impossible to get a tool that can do it all, and if you did manage to create it your hourly wage and time put into this effort might as well have been spent on a bunch of people manually copy and pasting.

So go for option 2!

A nice reference link: [How to say goodbye to your migration tool](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/how-to-say-goodbye-to-your-migration-tool)

Answer (score 0):

The *easiest* is to upgrade your R5.x database to 2011 or 2013, but it looks like you're doing a consolidation, so this might not be possible.

Tridion R5 has an XML-based API that can be accessed via the Business Connector SOAP service, but this may not be the easiest of things to do if you're rushed for time. Of course, you have the COM-based TOM available in R5 - but this only gives you local machine access to Tridion.

You can also use Content Porter, but I would expect some issues finding a version that works for both 2011 and R5 (depends on *what* R5 are we talking about - 5.1, 5.2 or 5.3 will all have support for different versions of the Content Porter).

We have had customers use software from [Kapow Software](http://kapowsoftware.com/) for migrations, but I cannot attest to how easy or simple these tools are as I have no hands-on experience with it.